# How to use date-picker in a react component using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with a form that should display a date picker

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    dateFrom: new Date(Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    dateTo: new Date()
  });

  const handleOnChange = e => {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={formData.dateFrom}
      name="dateFrom"
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
      onChange={e => handleOnChange(e)}
      />
  );
};
```

What I need to do is to save the new date in the state, and get it back to update the component useing its selected property.

the handleOnChange method works for other form controls, not for the date picker, the error I am getting says :

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which module/package you are using for DatePicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the callback of `onChange` on the `<DatePicker />` will have the value as first param, not the `event`, you can pass a similar Object to `handleOnChange` to keep it generic :

```
<DatePicker
  selected={formData.dateFrom}
  name="dateFrom"
  dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
  onChange={value => handleOnChange({target : { name: "dateForm", value}})}
/>
```